# Need Someone That Can Read This VBA Script! Fairly Simple

Tags: excel, vba, list

```
Public Sub MakeColumnsFromRows()
    Dim totalCutsToMake As Integer
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim currentCut As Integer
    Dim rowsToCut As Integer

    Sheets(1).Activate
    rowsToSkip = 10
    totalCutsToMake = (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count / rowsToSkip)
    currentColumn = 1

    Dim RowCount As Integer
    For currentCut = 1 To totalCutsToMake
        RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, currentColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(rowsToSkip + 1, currentColumn), Cells(RowCount, currentColumn + 1)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Cells(1, currentColumn + 2).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        currentColumn = currentColumn + 2
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is my VBA script, it cuts every 10 rows in the first two columns and then paste them adjacent in the next columns. (shortening a list of 500 rows into 50 list of 10 rows etc)

What I need: 
I have next to no experience with VBA, I am just trying to edit this script to select & cut the first 3 columns rather then the 2 that it currently cuts. This should be very simple for someone that can read the script easily. I can see it is in the 'Range' section however I have not spent the time to learn what the syntax is to change it.

If possible, edit the VBA script to cut the first 10 rows for the first 3 columns and then paste into the next 3 columns and repeat.

Please show me the edits to the range that made this possible.

Comment: "however I have not spent the time to learn what the syntax is to change it."

read the first line here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

"Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it."

ie. it's not for people who are too lazy to put forth any effort and just want their code written for them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Public Sub MakeColumnsFromRows()
    Dim totalCutsToMake As Integer
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim currentCut As Integer
    Dim rowsToCut As Integer

    Sheets(4).Activate
    rowsToSkip = 10
    totalCutsToMake = (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count / rowsToSkip)
    currentColumn = 1

    Dim RowCount As Integer
    For currentCut = 1 To totalCutsToMake
        RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, currentColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(rowsToSkip + 1, currentColumn), Cells(RowCount, currentColumn + 2)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Cells(1, currentColumn + 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        currentColumn = currentColumn + 3
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer to my question. I tried changing one of those fields to +3 however not both.
Thank you once again, there is helpful people on stackoverflow! :)

Comment: you are welcome but this type of questions are not usually posted here.